# How use authorized user to make requests to another project with the same ldap authorization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ldap

I can't make request to another project with the same auth

I've tried to make

```
req.basic_auth curent_user.username, current_user.encrypted_password
```

But it said currnet_user is not defined

I've tried to set in project2

```
skip_before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: :get_data
```

Bit it returns

```
{"status":"422","error":"Unprocessable Entity"}
```

The code is

```
uri = URI(["#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}", 'clients', Rails.configuration.system_client_name, 'project1', 'get_data'].join('/'))
res = nil
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
  :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https'
) do |http|
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri)
  # ??? req.basic_auth curent_user.username, current_user.encrypted_password

  res = http.request(req)
end
data = res.body
```

Project1

```
def get_data
  render json: {q: 1}, status: 200
end
```

Gems are the same in both projects

```
    devise_ldap_authenticatable (0.8.1)
      devise (>= 3.0)
      net-ldap (>= 0.3.1, < 0.6.0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made no auth

In project2:

```
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: : get_data
skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: : get_data
```

In project1:

```
uri = URI(["#{request.protocol}#{request.host_with_port}", 'clients', Rails.configuration.system_client_name, get_data, 'get_num_of_synonyms'].join('/'))
    res = nil
    Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
      :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https'
    ) do |http|
      req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri.request_uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')

      res = http.request(req)
    end
```